# QtCreator performance tunning

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qt-creator

I use QtCreator whenever I can although its performance is not great sometimes.
I have a feeling situation gets worse with large source files, to put a number here I'll say over 1000 lines.
It seems disabling a couple of Helper plugins makes it take less CPU.

Is there a way to know CPU usage by each plugin? Which plugins are the most CPU hungry?

Now I'm going with the following and CPU usage seems good (almost close to 1% all the time).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can disable the clangCodeModel plugin and cppCheck to reduce CPU usage but the main processing used by a background parser that tokenizes and read symbols from your source file. sometimes the third party library may contain myriad file count and make the Qtcreator slow. also, you can reduce the files that must parse by the "Clang Code Model" panel (Tools > Options > C++ > Code Model.).